# Two proofs of the same theorem for some elementary property of Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was reading two proofs for a theorem about some property in Measure.

Theorem:

Let (X,$\sum$,$\mu$) where X is a set, $\sum $ is the sigma algebra of the set X, and $\mu$ is a measure. If $A_i$ $\subset$ $\sum$ and $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 ...$, then we have $ \mu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i) = \lim_{i\to\infty} \mu(A_i)$

Proof:

1) Since $A_i \subset A_{i+1}$, we have $A = A_1 \bigcup A_2 \bigcup A_3 ... = A_1 \bigcup  (A_2 \setminus A_1) \bigcup (A_3\setminus A2) \bigcup... =B_1 \bigcup B_2 \bigcup B_3 ...$ where the $B_i $ are pairwise disjoint.

$\mu(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_i) = \lim_{i\to\infty} (\mu(B_1)+\mu(B_2)+...+\mu(B_i)) = \lim_{i\to\infty} \mu( B_1 \bigcup B_2 \bigcup ...\bigcup B_i) =  \lim_{i\to\infty} \mu(A_i)$

The limit exist because $\mu(A_i) \le \mu(A_{i+1})$ since $A_i \subset A_{i+1}$.

---

My quetion is specifically regarding the statement "The limit exist because $\mu(A_i) \le \mu(A_{i+1})$ since $A_i \subset A_{i+1}$."   That statement is given by the author. I am not sure how it is used in the proof above.

2) another proof for the same theorem can be found on Page 6 here:
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m206/measure_notes.pdf

the second proof here seems more easy to understand, except there is one part I don't understand which is after they define $A_j = \cup_{i=1}^{j} B_i$, it says  then $\mu(A_j) = \mu (\cup_{i=1}^{j} B_i)$. I understand this. But then it says "which implies that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_i) = \lim_{j\to\infty} \mu(A_j)$.

Can we just take the j to $\infty$, and then says $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_i) = \lim_{j\to\infty} \mu(A_j)$ like that?

Could someone kindly explain the first proof of the theorem? especially the steps in between? (i.e. how to go from the very left to the very right at the end?, and how that statement "The limit exist because..." is used in the proof?)

Comment: About the 1st proof: you have to know if the limit exists in order to talk about it. The fact that the sequence $(\mu(A_n))$ is increasing is enough to justify that.

Comment: actually I was thinking about the same thing that the sequence is increasing so....by the Monotone convergence theorem, it should converges or something like that. But the thing is the Monotone convergence theorem says the sequence has to be bounded above but it seems that we only know $\mu(A_i)$ is increasing but we don't know if it is bounded. Could you comment more. Thank you.

Comment: Dont complicate it as much. An increasing sequence of real numbers converges always to its supremum, either it is a number or infinity

Comment: It is often convenient, especially in Measure Theory, to extend $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ and say that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\infty$ means that  $\forall r\in \mathbb R\;\exists n_r\;\forall n>n_r\;(x_n>r).$  This includes the possibility that $x_n=\infty$ for some $n.$

Comment: Hi Daniel, I guess it is a definition to say a sequence approaches infinity. But is it possible to know is that definition for the purpose of saying the following: "The sequence $x_n$ CONVERGES TO INFINITY".  Is it the purpose for that definition? i.e. to say something like that (convergence to infinity) concretely? Because usually to say something concrete like (convergence of sequence, or continuity in real analysis or measure theory), they require delta-epsilon kind of proof. If so, does it apply to any of the proof above?  Could you point out where specifically. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple proof is to use the monotone convergence theorem (as the sequence $(1_{A_i})_i$ is increasing and positive):
$$
\mu(A)=\int_X1_A\,d\mu=\int_X\lim_i1_{A_i}\,d\mu=\lim_i\int_X1_{A_i}\,d\mu=\lim_i\mu(A_i).
$$

Remark: as $(A_i)_i$ is an increasing set sequence then $\lim_iA_i=\bigcup_iA_i=A$ and $1_A=\lim_i1_{A_i}$

Comment: could you explain the step? like how do you all of a sudden have a limit sign on the 3rd statement, and you have the limit moving outside of the integral on the 4th statement, and then you end up with that limit of $\mu(A_i)$ ?

Comment: The 3rd statement is explained in the remark, the 4th statement by the monotone convergence theorem and the end by the definition of the integral of a positive simple function !